# How to apply access control header to folders AND subfolders in Nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, cors

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file I currently have blocks along the lines of

```
 location /cdn
 {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
 }
```

which has worked well - up until now.  However, I now find myself creating sub directories below /cdn which throws up CORS errors on the browser when I try to access resources in, say `/cdn/appdata/icons`.  I could quite easily bung in a few more blocks similar to the one above but targeting `/cdn/appdata`  etc.  However, this would be a short term solution liable to break sooner rather than later.

Is there a way to specify a location block for a folder and ALL its subfolders?

Comment: The `location` in your question does that already, unless a more specific `location` matches.

Comment: Please share the output of `nginx -T` to show the full nginx configuration.